# Buttons are having default size.Why CSS is not working for buttons?

Tags: html, css

```
<tr><td align="center"><input type="button" name="login" value="Login" onclick="location.href='#'"></td></tr> 

<tr><td align="center"><input type="button" class="button" name="register" value="Register" onclick="location.href='#'"></td></tr>
```

And CSS for the buttons are as below

```
button{ 
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: there is no button in your code

Comment: i got it thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please do not stealth edit your question as it will have an effect on the answers given.

Comment: i got it thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have not written proper CSS. In HTML first button have input type there is no class and in the second button you have added `class="button"`.

You have written the css for `button` tag, not for `button` class. So here is the CSS for class and input type.

Try this CSS.

```
.button, input[type="button"]{ 
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have `button`, you have `input`.

Answer (score 1):

using this selector

```
input[type="button"]{}
```